# asp mvc get last insert id from savechanges()

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

im using poco code first . how do i get the last insert after savechanges() ?

thanks

Comment: What were you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 16):

I resolve that problem in such way:

with Max() - you can get last id from table

```
db.Products.Add(product);
db.SaveChanges();
int lastProductId = db.Products.Max(item => item.ProductId);
```

ProductId is Key() and increment

Comment: This will give a problem in a multi-user system. If another user saves a product 1 milli second after you, you will get his product Id number as it will be the max number at that time. It is a small chance but, it WILL happen!

Answer (score 11):

```
register = db.registers.CreateObject();
register.id = 0;
register.customer = h.customer;
register.employee = employee_created;
register.created = DateTime.Now;
db.registers.AddObject(register);
db.SaveChanges();

//You can get the ID here
int last_insert_id = register.id;
```

Answer (score 8):

After you've saved an entity in the context (SaveChanges()). The ID property on the poco itself should be set by the entity framework.

If you actually want more information about the modified entities, you can look for them in the ObjectStateManager provided by the Entity Framework's ObjectContext.

Comment: i was under the impression he wanted the last insert from a global table perspective, not a single save operation. i could be wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I now get the same feeling.

Comment: I have read the question a couple of times, and I still feel he wants to know the ID of the entity just created.

Comment: @J.Tihon Entity framework will set the ID of the entity itself, but if the POCO is mapped to the entity then the POCO will not be updated. I think the question is asking how to update the POCO from the updated entity.

Answer (score 4):

```
var newProduct = db.Product.Add(model);
db.SaveChanges();
var productId = model.Id;
```

It automatically adds it to the object you are saving

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following example -

```
db.Hotels.Add(hotels);
                db.SaveChanges();
                var id = hotels.Id;
```

It worked for me.

Source - https://dzone.com/articles/how-return-id-field-after