# Is it possible to save data into 2 tables using redirect to? Without Viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net, entity-framework-4

I have an issue, and I don't know what to do.

I have 2 tables that have a relationship between them (PK - FK), and I want to know if it's possible to add a new row in the first table then redirect that to the second table, and then add another new row then save data in both tables?

I have tried to do this but it's only inserting a new row just in the first, the second lets me enter data but when I save, it doesn't save in the second.

I have 2 separate controllers for each table but that is really what I want to know if it is possible and how. A basic example is really appreciated. Please bear in mind that I'm quite new at programing whit this technology.

Thank you, and sorry for any bad spelling!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very unclear. Are you looking for a way to save all the data at once or just create a workflow where the user can enter in both sets of data?

To save the data all at once you have two options. The first and best option is to simply include all the fields for both entities in one form. There doesn't have to be a 1-1 correlation between a controller and particular entity. You can work with multiple different entities in a single controller action. Utilizing a view model, you can work with all the data in one view and then map the posted information to all the appropriate entities and save them all at once.

The second option is to create a "wizard" or multi-step form. Since each request is idempotent, you just have to persist the data from each post in some way, generally `TempData`. In the final step, you can then retrieve the previous posted data from `TempData` or wherever else you persisted it and finally save all the entities.

If you're talking about two separate save steps as part of a work flow, that's even easier. You just follow the PRG (Post-Redirect-Get) pattern and just make your redirect the next step in the chain. However, this only directs the user down a defined path. It does not prevent the user from breaking the chain and failing to complete later steps.

Comment: Hello Chris. I'm sorry if my question is unclear, but I require something like the PRG pattern you just specified. So thank you! I will search for an example of that pattern to better understand that so I can apply it to my application. Thank you yet again. Cheers!

Comment: Chris my I ask another question on this topic? I did it and it works, but can you send me a reference on how to get the last inserted ID (PK) and display it when I redirect to the other table's view? For example I have PK with value 3 and when I redirect to the other view I want to display this value "3" in the field of the FK? I searched something but I didn't quite understand it. For example this link: " http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103792/asp-mvc-get-last-insert-id-from-savechanges  " but I don't understand how do you display it (the FK value). Many thanks again for all your help.

Comment: When you do the redirect, you should include that information, e.g. `return RedirectToAction("Foo", new { id = 3 });`.

Comment: Thank you for your replay Chris, I did this: ' db.tbl_NIR.Add(nir);
                    db.SaveChanges(); var ni = db.tbl_NIR.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).FirstOrDefault().ID; return RedirectToAction("AddIO", new { id = ni }); ' in the HttpPost method but It does nothing to display that value, I know this is something that I didn't do in the view, this is my editor for in the view: "@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NirID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })". I think that this is the problem, so if you can give me any advice on it, I will really appreciate it.